# Java: How implement AES with 128 bits with CFB and No Padding

Tags: java, encryption

could someone give me any lead to this problem ?
I need to know how to encrypt and decrypt with AES with at least 128 bits with CFB and No Padding.

Some code or links will be very appreciated. (i already look on google, but no lucky tough).

UPDATE:

Works fine!

```
public byte[] crypt() {
    byte[] crypt = null;
    try {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
        final SecretKey skeySpec = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        crypt = cipher.doFinal(new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3});


    } catch (Exception ex) {
         throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
        return crypt;
}
```

Returns null .. why ?

```
public String decrypt(byte[] text) {
    byte[] crypt = null;
    String plainText = null;
    try {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
        final SecretKey skeySpec = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        crypt = cipher.doFinal(text);
        plainText = new String(crypt);



    } catch (Exception ex) {
          throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
        return plainText;
}
```

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: Don't swallow the exception! Rethrow it using `catch (Exception ex) { throw new RuntimeException(ex); }`

Comment: Sorry about that, i fix it and appears:
"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing"
Do you know what means ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Happy googling!

Answer (score 3):

Give this a go:

```
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
final SecretKey skeySpec = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")
        .generateKey();
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cipher.doFinal(new byte[] { 0, 1, 2,
            3 })));
```

Comment: thanks by the help.
i could encrypt using your code, but how to decrypt ?
i already try but isn't working..

Comment: I guess you'll need to set Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE... you'll have to deal with instantiating a SecretKey object too. Maybe update your question with the code that doesn't work for you.